# How to draw a simple directed graph

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I can draw a simple directed force graph like this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <title>Force Layout Example 1</title>
    <style>

.node {
    fill: #ccc;
    stroke: #fff;
    stroke-width: 2px;
}

.link {
    stroke: #777;
    stroke-width: 2px;
}

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <script src='http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js'></script>
    <script>

var width = 640,
    height = 480;
    constant = 174

var nodes = [
    { x:   constant, y: 215 , width:50,height:50  },
    { x: 2*constant, y: 215 ,width:50,height:50 },
    { x: 3*constant, y: 215 ,width:50,height:50 },
    { x: 4*constant, y: 215 ,width:50,height:50 }
];


var links = [
    { source: 0, target: 1 }
];

var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg')
    .attr('width', width)
    .attr('height', height);


var force = d3.layout.force()
    .size([width, height])
    .nodes(nodes)
    .links(links);


force.linkDistance(width/2);


var link = svg.selectAll('.link')
    .data(links)
    .enter().append('line')
    .attr('class', 'link');


var node = svg.selectAll('.node')
    .data(nodes)
    .enter().append('rect')
    .attr('class', 'node');

force.on('end', function() {

    node.attr('x', function(d) { return d.x; })
        .attr('y', function(d) { return 215; })
        .attr('width', function(d) { return d.width; })
        .attr('height', function(d) { return d.height; });

    link.attr('x1', function(d) { return d.source.x; })
        .attr('y1', function(d) { return d.source.y; })
        .attr('x2', function(d) { return d.target.x; })
        .attr('y2', function(d) { return d.target.y; });

});


force.start();

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

which gives me output like:

[image]

I want to achieve this:

[image]

I'm not sure how I can change the above code to add the text inside the rectangle. I also want the rectangle to be rounded!

I tried the following for the text piece:

```
node.append('text').text('A')
    .attr('x', 174)
    .attr('y', 250)
    .attr('fill', 'black')
```

However, that doesn't work. I'm not sure how to achieve that. Any clue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Instead of `.enter().append('rect')`, start with `.enter().append('g')`, then you can append `rect` and `text` elements onto the `g`.  You then use `attr("transform", "translate(" + ... + ")")` in the force tick callback to position everything in the `g` nodes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual code for inserting text in that style would be as follows:

```
node.append("text").style("text-anchor", "middle")
    .style("pointer-events", "none")
    .style("font-weight", 900)
    .attr("fill", "white")
    .style("stroke-width", "0.3px")
    .style("font-size", "16px")
    .attr("y", function (d){return d.height/2+6;})
    .attr("x", function (d){return d.width/2;})
    .text(function (d) {return d.label;});
```

Here is a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gj2y87z8/) that is very similar to your image. Some notable changes:

- Nodes have an additional field of 'label' (A,B,C,D). Could also use an integer->char to automatically assign this using the index of the node.
- Added all the necessary links
- 'Node' variable now contains `g` (group) elements which then have the `rect` AND `text` added. These elements are then translated according to the `node.x` and `node.y` fields, which moves both text and rect at once.
- Stylized rectangles. Rounded using `rx` and `ry`, and coloured using `.style("fill", "#2376B2")`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: how can I make the arrow with head?

Comment: You have to add a marker object to the `defs` section, and then add that into the `marker-end` or `marker-mid` attribute of the links. A simple arrowhead path is: `M 0 0 12 9 0 18 3 9`. To make things easier, change the `lines` to `paths` and then attach to `marker-mid`. This also requires a slight change to the line initialization. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gj2y87z8/6/). If you want the marker on the head of the arrow you can keep them as lines but have to code to account for the width/height of the rectangle (since it currently anchors to the middle, causing arrowheads to be hidden).

Answer (score 0):

I've made a free and lightweight library that may be useful to others:

[Arg-Graph is a simple free library for creating directed SVG graphs or diagram using JQuery.](https://github.com/n-yousefi/Arg-Graph) 
[image: Directed Graph]